# Controlling ColorFunctionScaling

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to control the scaling of `ColorFunction` beside just to turn it off and on with `ColorFunctionScaling`?

Two problems with this approach are:

1. Repeating colours if the scaling is small compared to the plot range.

   [image]
2. Uniform colour if the scaling is large compared to the plot range.

   [image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` rescales the value to lie between 0 and 1. You can explicitly control the scaling of the `ColorFunction` by setting `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` and implementing the rescaling in the `ColorFunction` itself. The following examples should clarify what these options do and how to design your own:

#### Default behaviour

```
Plot[2 Cos[x], {x, 0, 4 π}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], ImageSize -> 300,
    ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"], ColorFunctionScaling -> #] & /@ {True, False} // Row
```

[image]

You see that with `True`, all the values are rescaled to lie between 0 and 1 before passing to the `ColorFunction`, whereas with `False`, the values greater than 1 and less than 0 are clipped to 1 and 0 respectively.

In other words, the following setting (for the example above):

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorFunction -> cf
```

is equivalent to

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> (cf@Rescale[#2, {min, max}, {0, 1}]&)
```

where `cf` is the color function and `min` and `max` are the minimum and maximum values of the function you're plotting (for the values being plotted), which in this case are `-2` and `2` respectively.

#### Custom rescaling

The explanation above should give you an idea of how to go about implementing your custom rescaling function. Here's an example that exponentially varies from approximately 0.22 to 1:

```
Plot[2 Cos[x], {x, 0, 4 π}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"]@Exp@Rescale[#2, {-2, 2}, {-1.5, 0}]&)]
```

[image]