# Individual ColorFunction with RGBColor

Tags: plotting, color

I want to create a custom `ColorFunction` using `RGBColor` for my `DensityPlot`. A nice example is provided in the `ColorFunction` documentation under "[applications](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html)".

I'm trying to get this coloring:

1. If zero: set color to Black.
2. If positive: increase Blue.
3. If negative: increase Red.

My code looks like this:

```
DensColor[ z_ ] := RGBColor[If[z < 0, -z, 0], 0, (z + Abs[z])/2]
f[x_, y_] := x*y - 1
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Full, ColorFunction -> DensColor, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Unfortunately, it gives blue for positive (correct), but still some dark-blue for zero (wrong), and no red at all (wrong).

Can anyone explain why this isn't working as I expected?

Comment: Set `ColorFunctionScaling->False`

Comment: Related [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58951/7167) or [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21687/7167)

Comment: @bobthechemist thanks, that works now. I didn't find these related questions here (which now explain the issue). However, I dont understand why Wolframs example (which indeed has negative values) does not need `ColorFunctionScaling`.

Comment: Try one of the documentation examples with `ColorFunctionScaling` to see the difference, for example [http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dud45.png].

Comment: With `ColorFunctionScaling->True` (which is the default), Mathematica delivers values to the color function that are scaled to lie between 0 and 1. This is also the range that the CoolColor function in the example expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is put an answer on record.

As bobthechemist noted in a comment, the OP's code only needs to be given the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False,`. When this is done

```
DensColor[z_] := RGBColor[If[z < 0, -z, 0], 0, (z + Abs[z])/2]
f[x_, y_] := x*y - 1
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  ColorFunction -> DensColor,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility is to use `Blend[]` in conjunction with an appropriately scaled sigmoidal function that takes values in $(0,1)$. `LogisticSigmoid[]` is a particularly convenient function for this application:

```
DensityPlot[x y - 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
            ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Black, Blue}, LogisticSigmoid[#]] &), 
            ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic,
            PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: red, black, and blue/colors scaled just for you]