# Help with ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color

I'm trying to graph a list of data with `ListDensityPlot`. My idea is to color negative values in red, zero in white and positive values in blue. I created a `ColorFunction` using `Blend`:

```
cf = Blend[{Blue,White,Red},#]&
ListDensityPlot[mydata, ColorFunction -> cf, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Right now when I graph my data white is around -3. I could manually "center" my data, but I'm wondering whether there is a way to "center" the graph around white (zero) on the fly (by supplying options to `ListDensityPlot` or modifying `cf`).

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60285)?

Comment: This helps, but I find `LogisticSigmoid` to be too sharp around 0 and with not much variation for `Abs[x] > 4`. I guess I could find a better function.

Comment: @Jens, not exactly a duplicate...

Comment: You can tune `LogisticSigmoid`'s argument of course, to make the "s" more or less steep.

Comment: True, actually that is more elegant. I ended up using `cf = Blend[{Blue, White, Red}, LogisticSigmoid[#/3]] &`.

Comment: …and of course, if `LogisticSigmoid[]` still doesn't suit you, there's `ArcTan[]`, `Tanh[]`, `Erf[]`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple option:

```
ListDensityPlot[mydata, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-10, Blue}, {0, White}, {5, Red}}, #] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

A simple way to control blend:

```
minLegend = Min[mydata[[;; , -1]]];
maxLegend = Max[mydata[[;; , -1]]];
spdLegend = 2;

cf = Blend[{{minLegend , Blue}, {minLegend / spdLegend, LightBlue}, {0, White},
     {maxLegend / spdLegend, LightRed}, {maxLegend , Red}}, #] &;

ListDensityPlot[mydata, ColorFunction -> cf, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I guess I could also dynamically change the extremes with `Min[data[[;;,-1]]]` and `Max[data[[;;,-1]]]`. How do I change the "speed" of the blend?

Comment: @amrods `cf = Blend[{{-10, Blue}, {-5, LightBlue}, {0, White}, {2.5, 
      LightRed}, {5, Red}}, #] &;` you could control when `LightBlue` and `LightRed` start based on the desired speed.

Comment: I see, awesome.